# Is GGPoker random and reputable?

Tags: online

Does anyone have any evidence as to the randomness on the site GG Poker? Also, is it a reputable site? I've read some horror stories online, albeit a year or two ago, and I'm wondering if anyone in the community has some data they can point to (e.g., hand history database), can attest for a positive experience with customer support on the site, or see any glaring problems with the TOS at present.

Answer (score -2):

It is the fastest growing online poker room that signed a number of pros to represent it and is investing ridiculous amounts of money in marketing, so I do not see how it could be a scam.

I also have an account on that network for quite a long time and did not had a single problem with moving money or anything else, so it sure looks legit to me.

As for databases, GG network does not allow HUDs or hand mining so you can't check it yourself, but like other rooms, it is audited and I have no reasons to believe they would risk doing anything shady since they are in a great position to become a significant force in this industry.

In general, people want to believe that online poker is not fair, but there is no evidence to back it up, and here is an [article about it](https://www.mypokercoaching.com/online-poker-rigged/) (*MOD: link is post authors own site*). While there is surely some cheating going on in online poker like a team playing, using assistance software, and so on, but I do not believe that regulated sites would to something to scam their players since they simply make more money from the rake.

Comment: Re: `In general, people want to believe that online poker is not fair, but there is no evidence to back it up, and here is an article about it. ` - There have been numerous examples over the past 10-15 years of nefarious activity by online poker sites. In general that is why people are concerned, but I agree with your point that there is a bias to presume it is "rigged."

Comment: Looping back to this, I am downvoting this because (1) The link is to your site; (2) due to the general dismissive tone of the answer; and (3) because of your first point: `It is the fastest growing online poker room that signed a number of pros to represent it and is investing ridiculous amounts of money in marketing, so I do not see how it could be a scam.`. See this widely publicized incident for a counterpoint (on Forbes, not my own website): https://www.forbes.com/sites/corporateresolutions/2011/09/27/full-tilt-poker-fraud-how-ftp-threw-egg-on-the-poker-face/#51ea424586b4

Comment: Your example is completely irrelevant here since Full Tilt case was mostly made not from pros they hired to represent the site but from the owners, and I am quite sure a lot has changed over 9 years :) secondly, linking to an article on that topic does not change a single thing be it on my site or not, any chance you can share at least a couple of that numerous examples of online poker being "rigged" over the years that you mentioned?

Comment: Saying "here is an article about it" that you authored is disingenuous.